# How to get series's id in Highcharts / Highstock

Tags: highcharts

How to get Series's id? In the [**API**](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#Series) there is only name and data etc. But don't have id. How could I get id from series?

I'm using the following way to loop all series in chart.

```
$(chart.series).each(function(i, serie){

    // Want to get serie's id

});
```

EDIT:

I found i can get id using the follow way. I'm not sure is it the right way?

```
 $(chart.series).each(function(i, serie){
        console.log(serie.options.id);

 });
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you know the id of series already you can get a reference to the series by 
`chart.get(ID)`

If you want to loop through all the series and list all the IDs of series, do this:

```
 $(chart.series).each(function(i, serie){console.log(serie.options.id)})
```

FIddle : http://jsfiddle.net/NaK9D/2/

Comment: Thanks. I feel it should be in document.

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation:

> Another way to reference the series programmatically is by id. Add an id in the series configuration options, and get the series object by chart.get(id).

Looks like you can do:

```js
$(chart.series).each(function(i, serie){
  this.get(id);
});
```

Comment: I tried but got `Uncaught ReferenceError: id is not defined `

Comment: Have you added the id to the series options?

Comment: Yes, each series has its own id. `var ser = chart.addSeries({
                                    id: name1,
                                    selected: true,
                                    yAxis: 'value_axis',
                                    name: name + " " + para_array[name1][1],
                                    data: data[1]
                                });`

Comment: Please see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dodoflying/NaK9D/1/ , id is not defined.