# unable to get series id in HighCharts chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I've followed the hint in a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16472331/how-to-get-seriess-id-in-highcharts-highstock) to write a code line to get the HighCharts series by means of their id. Unfortunately, I was unable to do it.
Consider the following toy example ([on Jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2gxxupb8/3/)):

```
$(function () {
    var cseries=[{
            id: 'Tokyo',
            name: 'Tokyo',
            data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
        }, {
            id: 'New York',
            name: 'New York',
            data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5]
        }];
    $('#container').highcharts({
        series: cseries
    });
var chart=$('#container').highcharts();
alert(chart.get('Tokyo').id);
});
```

When I cut the last line, the script goes well. When I don't cut the last line, the alert returns `undefined`. Why?

Comment: there is no function as **chart.get('id').id**...it is **chart.get('id')**,
link http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not closing enough brackets on the alert:

```
alert(chart.get('Tokyo');
```

should be:

```
alert(chart.get('Tokyo'));
```

And I think you would be better off doing a `console.log(chart.get('Tokyo'));` and see the output in the browser console, since it outputs an object which cannot be displayed in an alert.

Update based on post edit:
`chart.get('Tokyo')` does not have an `id` property

To get the series id, try `console.log(chart.get('Tokyo').userOptions.id);`

Comment: Sorry, I've already recognized my mistake and updated the question. I'm unable, yet.

Comment: The `chart.get('Tokyo')` object does not have an `id` property. What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: I'm looking for the id property, since I've defined it for every element of chart series array.

Comment: Found it! it's "hidden" inside the `userOptions` property. Please see updated answer

Comment: Well, that `chart.get('Tokyo') ` does return the series. Have you checked how it looks in the console? It returns an object with all its properties.